# Adding "Invalid Entry" To Python Dice Roller

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have a Python dice rolling simulator:

```
from random import randint

play = True

while play:
    roll = randint(1, 6)
    print(roll)
    answer = input("Roll again? (y/n)")
    print(answer)
    if answer == "y":
        play = True
    elif answer == "n":
        break
```

If you input anything other than "y" or "n" it will roll again. I would like to make it so that it will say something like "invalid entry" instead of rolling again. How could I change this to do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate the answer and ask again if it is invalid like

```
from random import randint

play = True

while play:
    roll = randint(1, 6)
    print(roll)
    ask = True
    while ask:
        answer = input("Roll again? (y/n)")
        print(answer)
        if (answer != "y") and (answer != "n"):
            print("Invalid input")
        else:
            ask = False
    if answer == "y":
        play = True
    elif answer == "n":
        break
```